# Convert acf/gutenberg markup to html

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, json

I am setting up a json feed with content of some of my pages. My problem is that I use ACF and Gutenberg, so `get_the_content()` returns the ACF markup which is basically a HTML comment with json.

Is there any way to convert this to HTML markup?

Right now (before json_encode), my array looks like this:

```
[59] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1127
            [title] => About page
            [type] => page
            [date] => 2023-04-03 08:47:47
            [content] => <!-- wp:acf/page-title {"name":"acf/page-title","data":{"background-image":"no","_background-image":"field_conditionaljeydheysjwui","breadcrumb":"1","_breadcrumb":"field_srqts561nagbe","type":"image","_type":"field_conditional172638473628","image_source":"","_image_source":"field_cy3tfsuv9v32y","image":"","_image":"field_in9vpqxwc2elk","aspect_ratio":"auto","_aspect_ratio":"field_bw08fr0ujadtf","object_fit":"cover","_object_fit":"field_5rvr10nnlw5qc","":"","_":"field_wyetdgedwje16a","heading-lower-case":"Lorem ipsum","_heading-lower-case":"field_eewyhsyejduws4"},"mode":"preview"} /-->

<!-- wp:acf/submenu {"name":"acf/submenu","data":{"heading":"Lorem ipsum","_heading":"field_rwts61bxncmdj","text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. .\r\n\r\n\u0026nbsp;","_text":"field_tarq5w62711jt","spacing_top":"medium","_spacing_top":"field_0hw06y22crmln","spacing_bottom":"medium","_spacing_bottom":"field_fbgn4tkty0rjm","":"","_":"field_ubapqoslw8161p"},"mode":"preview"} /-->
        )
```

I would like for it to be converted to HTML, so something like this:

```
[59] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1127
            [title] => About page
            [type] => page
            [date] => 2023-04-03 08:47:47
            [content] => '<h2>Lorem ipsum</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>'
        )
```

Are there any functions that are able to do this?

Comment: note that in the core standard REST API responses for posts there is a rendered content field that can be used, you don't have to build out a custom JSON response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use [`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) the [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) hook gets applied to the content, which is when blocks get rendered into HTML. This hook doesn't run when using `get_the_content()`, so you'll need to run it manually:

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
```

Comment: Okay, I see. Looks like it worked, thank you :)